# How do i run node save in background process

Tags: nodes

I have created drupal website for ecommerce store.

Issue:
After node save i will redirect to thankyou (destination) page for tracking but it takes long time to complete.
Customer may skip if it takes long time to complete the process.

How do i run node save in background process and display thankyou page immediately after placed order.

I want to track order conversions and node save.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Yadavan

Comment: You might be able to do this by altering the Drupal node save form `hook_form_alter` and redirecting it to the Drupal queue API. It is however not the Drupal way, and would require quite a lot of custom code to achieve. And what if the process fails? The user will be under the impression all was fine.

Comment: You could save in background but as Neograph734 says, you have to be careful about what could happen if there  an error during node save in background.
Could you tell us how much time takes to save the node?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead of saving the node directly, modify the node object with attributes from the form and then add it to a queue so you can use the [Drupal queue system](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7) to do the actual `node_save()` operation on it.